# Kendo Grid - Custom Editor, Update Not Firing, Rows Deleting

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a grid with a datasource loaded locally (not using transport).  I was able to create a custom editor which adds checkboxes to a row when user clicks "edit" button.  Can't use the default editor since I have to do a per-field check to see if user is authorized to change a field.

Clicking "edit" button does what I expect, it displays checkboxes where it should.  However, upon changing data and clicking "update" button, the row deletes.  Or when in "edit" mode and user clicks another "edit" button in a different row, the original row deletes or console error about null data.

Update event never seems to fire either so that I can manually handle updating data source.

```
dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  data: result,                         
  change: function(e){
  console.log('a change happened');
  console.log(e);                               
  },
  schema: {
    model: {
      id: "uid",
      fields: {
        lastName: {editable:false},
        firstName: {editable:false},
        email: {editable:false},
        accountNum: {editable:false},
        email: {editable:false},
        status: {editable:true},
        RQ:{editable:true, type:"boolean"},
        RR:{editable:true, type:"boolean"},
        ER:{editable:true, type:"boolean"},     
      }
    }
  },
  batch: true,
  pageSize: 50
});


$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource, 
    editable: "inline",
    pageable: {
        refresh: false,
        pageSize: 50,
        pageSizes: [
            50,
            100,
            200
        ]
    },
    filterable: {
        extra: false,
        operators: {
            string: {
                contains: "Contains",
                startswith: "Starts with"
            },          
        }
    },
    reorderable: true,
    resizable: true,
    columns: columnsettings,
    edit: function(e){
        //$('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
        console.log('an edit happened');
        console.log(e);
        //e.preventDefault();
    },
    cancel: function(e){
        //$('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
        //$('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.sync();
        console.log('cancel happened');
        console.log(e);
        //e.preventDefault();
        $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
    },
    update: function(e){
        console.log('an update happened');
        console.log(e);
    },
    change: function(e){
        console.log('a change happened not datasource one');
        console.log(e);
    },
    saveChanges: function(e){
        console.log('a save is about to occurr');
        console.log(e);
    },
    // get grid state to save to DB
    dataBound: function(e){
        var grid = this;
        var dataSource = this.dataSource;
        var state = kendo.stringify({
            page: dataSource.page(),
            pageSize: dataSource.pageSize(),
            sort: dataSource.sort(),
            group: dataSource.group(),
            filter: dataSource.filter()
        });
    }
});





function customInlineEditor(container, options){
        var currentField = options.field;
        var inputField;
        if(options.model[currentField] === true){
            inputField = $('<input type="checkbox" data-value-field="'+currentField+'" name="'+currentField+'" checked>');
        }else if(options.model[currentField] === false){
            inputField = $('<input type="checkbox" name="'+currentField+'">');
        }else{
            //inputField = "Locked";
        }
        container.append(inputField);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kendo Grid without transports defined is designed to just 'display' the data, not to edit it. What you can do instead of using event handlers for events such as 'save', 'update', 'edit' is to declare the transport operations as functions.

```
var data = [
  { Id: 1, Name: "Decision 1", Position: 1 },
  { Id: 2, Name: "Decision 2", Position: 2 },
  { Id: 3, Name: "Decision 3", Position: 3 }
];

var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  //data: data,
  transport: {
    read: function(e) {                                
      e.success(data);
    },
    update: function(e) {                                
      e.success();
    }, 
    create: function(e) {
      var item = e.data;
      item.Id = data.length + 1;
      e.success(item);
    }
  },
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/OzOdiLAf/1/edit) is an example that should be working fine.

Comment: This allowed me to edit a record, and the change is saved to screen.  Still the weird issue of deleting a row when one row is in edit mode and another edit button is clicked.  Any thoughts on that would also be appreciated.  Thanks big time though on the explanation of local data.

Comment: Modify the example and share a link so I can see that weird behavior and investigate.

Comment: Yeah I am wondering if the version I'm using has a bug... v2013.1.319

Comment: In my scenario I had to define the scheme in order to get the update callback properly, as it's in the example link.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is late in the game, I thought it would benefit others to see an entire data source.

One problem with some of the Kendo-related documentation, is that some of the examples don't go far enough and reflect actual real-world implementation.

```
        return new kendo.data.DataSource({
            type: "odata",
            transport: {
                read:
                    function (options) {
                        var odataParams = kendo.data.transports["odata"].parameterMap(options.data, "read");

                        dataFactory.getList(odataParams)
                            .success(function (result) {
                                options.success(result);
                            })
                            .error(function (error) {
                                console.log("data error");
                            });

                        //$http({
                        //    url: crudServiceBaseUrl,
                        //    method: 'GET',
                        //    params: odataParams
                        //})
                        //.success(function (result) {
                        //    options.success(result);
                        //});
                    },
                //{
                //    url: crudServiceBaseUrl,
                //    dataType: "json"
                //},



                // {function (options) {
                //    //var odataParams = kendo.data.transports["odata"].parameterMap(options.data, "read");   // "{"take":"10","skip":"0","page":"1","pageSize":"10"}"
                //    (new abstractFactory2().query({ odataUrl: crudServiceBaseUrl })).$getAll()
                //        .then(function (data) {
                //            return options.success(data);
                //        });


                //var odataParams = kendo.data.transports["odata"].parameterMap(options.data, "read");   // "{"take":"10","skip":"0","page":"1","pageSize":"10"}"
                //contentTypeFactory.getList()
                //    .success(function (data) {
                //        return options.success(data);
                //    })
                //    .error(function (error) {
                //        console.log(error);
                //    });
                //},
                update:
                    function (options) {
                        //var odataParams = kendo.data.transports["odata"].parameterMap(options.data, "update");
                        var data = options.data;
                        dataFactory.update(data.ContentTypeId, data)
                            .success(function (result) {
                                // call standard error message function
                                customFunctions.showConfirmation();
                                options.success(result);
                            })
                            .error(function (error) {
                                customFunctions.showError("Update Failed"); // use default error message
                                console.log("data error");
                            });

                        //{ // PUT
                        //url: function (data) {
                        //    console.log(data);
                        //    dataType: "json"
                        //    return crudServiceBaseUrl + "(" + data.ContentTypeId + ")";
                        //},
                        //error: function (e) {
                        //    console.log("error: " + e);
                        //}
                    },
                create:
                    function (options) {
                        var data = options.data;
                        data.ContentTypeId = "0";           // required for valid field data
                        dataFactory.insert(data)
                            .success(function (result) {
                                options.success(result);
                            })
                            .error(function (error) {
                                customFunctions.showError("Create Failed"); // use default error message
                            });

                        //{ // POST
                        //data: function (data) {
                        //    // reformat the data to match the DTO
                        //    data.ContentTypeId = "0";
                        //    data.NumberOfContentTypes = "0";
                        //    //data.msrepl_tran_version = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000";
                        //    return data;
                        //},
                        //url: function (data) {
                        //    console.log(data);
                        //    return crudServiceBaseUrl;
                        //},
                        //error: function (e) {
                        //    console.log("create error: " + e);
                        //},
                        //dataType: "json",
                    },
                destroy:
                    function (options) {
                        var data = options.data;
                        dataFactory.remove(data.ContentTypeId)
                            .success(function (result) {
                                options.success(result);
                            })
                            .error(function (error) {
                                console.log("data error");
                            });

                        //{
                        //url: function (data) {
                        //    dataType: "json";
                        //    return crudServiceBaseUrl + "(" + data.ContentTypeId + ")";
                        //},
                        //success: function (e) {
                        //    console.log("success");
                        //},
                        //error: function (e) {
                        //    console.log(e);
                        //}
                    },
                parameterMap: function (options, type) {
                    // this is optional - if we need to remove any parameters (due to partial OData support in WebAPI
                    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                        return JSON.stringify({ models: options });
                    }
                    //var parameterMap = kendo.data.transports.odata.parameterMap(options);

                    //delete parameterMap.$inlinecount;               // remove inlinecount parameter
                    //delete parameterMap.$format;                    // remove format parameter

                    //return parameterMap;
                },

            },
            batch: false,
            pageSize: 10,
            serverPaging: true,
            change: function (e) {
                console.log("change: " + e.action);
                // do something with e
            },
            schema: {
                data: function (data) {
                    //console.log(data)
                    return data.value;
                },
                total: function (data) {
                    console.log("count: " + data["odata.count"]);
                    return data["odata.count"];
                },
                model: {
                    id: "ContentTypeId",
                    fields: {
                        ContentTypeId: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                        //UserId: {editable: false, nullable: false },
                        Description: { type: "string", validation: { required: true } },
                        //msrepl_tran_version: { type: "string", validation: { required: true } }
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function (e) {
                //var response = JSON.parse(e.responseText);
                var response = e.status;
                console.log(response);
            }
        })  // dataSource
```

This is full KendoUI OData datasource and initially used the default KendoUI way of doing things (commented out sections in the different transport sections - left in for reference).  What's different about this is that it exposes the Kendo options and stores them in `odataParams`, then passes them off to an [AngularJS factory provider](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) that handles the communication.

Take note of the `parameterMap:` section, and set a break-point there to see what goes through there, for reference.

There is some additional debugging `console.log()`'s put in there.

Hope this is of benefit.